# Error in Updating Square Order after creating invoice

Tags: square

I am using Square SDK for dotnet and I am creating an order and then creating invoice and then updating the same order. I am using same api key, same customer and same location for all these operations but it is breaking at update call giving following error.

> Category: "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR"
> Code: "FORBIDDEN"
> Detail: "LineItems cannot be modified for orders owned by another application."
> Field: "order.line_items"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for posting! Can you update your question to provide a specific code example of what triggered the error message? That will help other users provide a helpful answer. Check here for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The error should be better, but essentially once you actually create the invoice, you can't edit the line items that would affect the amount. Per the [documentation](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/invoices-api/overview#limitations):

> Updating an order. You cannot update order fields (such as line items, taxes, and discounts) that change the order amount. To update these order fields, you must cancel the invoice, which also cancels the order (sets the order status to CANCELED). You then create a new order and a new invoice. You can update order fields that do not change the order amount.